# Convert JNI types to Native types

Tags: java-native-interface, android-ndk

While there is documentation regarding turning a `jstring` to a native string (`string nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(jStringVariable, NULL);`)  I can't find an example which will convert a `jboolean` to a `bool` or a `jint` to an `int`.

Can anyone suggest how this is achieved?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You just need to cast `jint`to `int` using C style casts. Same for `jboolean` to `bool` (if you're using C99 `bool` type) or to `uint8_t` (if you're using std int types) or to `unsigned char`.

Open `$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h` and you'll see `jint`, `jboolean` etc are just `typedef`s.

Comment: You mean int intValue = (int) jIntValue; ?

Comment: exactly, C style cast will do the job

Comment: I don't know, you're asking how to convert a `jint` to an `int` and the answer is `jint` is just a `typedef` to `int` or `int32_t` depending on the platform

Comment: You're right. I'll ask a separate question for the problems which spring from this being true.

Comment: Is this same for int to jint, and bool to jboolean too?

Comment: Is it hold true for `int` to `jint` ?

Answer (score 30):

To cast a `jboolean` (which may only contain the values `JNI_FALSE` or `JNI_TRUE`) to a native `bool` I would use something like this :

```
(bool)(jboolean == JNI_TRUE)
```

If perhaps the `jboolean` isn't coming from the JVM, then testing for `jboolean != JNI_FALSE` might be considered safer.

Comment: That's a little limiting.  I think (bool)(java_rtn != JNI_FALSE) is better because some libraries may return true as some integer not equal to 1 (and JNI_TRUE == 1).

Comment: @greg7gkb umm, whut?!  What "library" are you talking about?  The JVM should guarantee that a `boolean` passed from Java to C will be exactly 0 or 1.

Comment: @Alnitak Most functions of the Windows API returns 0 if there was an error, and ANY VALUE OTHER THAN 0 if the function succeeded. So, a function can succeed and return a value, for example, of 28, and using the code of this answer, it will be converted to false.

Comment: @BloodShura the question was about converting _from_ Java's `jboolean` to native, not the other way around, so what the Windows API might do here is irrelevant.

Comment: @Alnitak The problem is that, not always the jboolean's will come directly from the JVM. You can cast a bool type (that can come from any other source like, for example, the Windows APIs) to a jboolean, and then, it is possible to this jboolean have more values than only 0s and 1s. Then, for the sake of security, it is better to check if the value is different than zero, rather than checking equality to one.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue–fixed. In my case I'm using openFrameworks so I don't know if this applies to non-openFrameworks projects (haven't tested). However, it appears that the first two arguments in an external function are always "env" and "thiz" and these need to be defined explicitly for each new extern function.

```
extern "C"{

// casts the variable properly
void Java_com_package_JavaClass_someFunction( JNIEnv*  env, jobject  thiz, jboolean yourBool ){
    myTestApp->someFunction( (bool) yourBool );
}

// "yourBool" will always be "1" because its taking the spot of "thiz" which is not null
void Java_com_package_JavaClass_someFunction( JNIEnv*  env, jboolean yourBool ){
    myTestApp->someFunction( (bool) yourBool );
}

// "yourBool" will always be "1" because its taking the spot of "env" which is not null
void Java_com_package_JavaClass_someFunction( jboolean yourBool ){
    myTestApp->someFunction( (bool) yourBool );
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The odd one out is `jchar`. It's defined as `unsigned short`, and depending on your compilation settings, that may or may not be equivalent to `wchar_t`. Depending on your underlying platform, you may be better off working with UTF8 strings. At least those are bitwise equivalent to ASCII for the ASCII subset of characters.

On Windows and Mac OS/Cocoa, however, the native wide string representation is exactly `unsigned short`. Java strings fit naturally into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use it in if(..) statement, this is working for me without conversion:

```
if (jboolean == true) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:

```
bool isValue = bool(jbooleanValue);
```

Comment: Adding some commentary why this answers the OP's question will help future people trying to find answers to similar questions.